# Cruisecontrol(orignal) can't not run program "svn" (in directory ....)

Tags: cruisecontrol

I instal CruiseControl 2.8.3 ,svn,
and use config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cruisecontrol>
<project name="xxxx">
 <property name="maven_home" value="F:/xxx/df/apache-maven-2.2.1"/>

 <listeners>
  <currentbuildstatuslistener file="logs/${project.name}/status.txt" />
 </listeners>
 <bootstrappers>
  <svnbootstrapper localWorkingCopy="projects/${project.name}" />
 </bootstrappers>
 <modificationset quietperiod="30">
  <svn localWorkingCopy="projects/${project.name}" />
 </modificationset>
 <schedule interval="60">
  <maven2 mvnhome="${maven_home}" pomfile="projects/${project.name}/pom.xml"
   goal="clean test" />
 </schedule>
 <log>
  <merge dir="projects/${project.name}/target/surefire-reports" />
 </log>
 <publishers>
  <onsuccess>
   <artifactspublisher dest="artifacts/${project.name}"
    file="projects/${project.name}/target/${project.name}.jar" />
  </onsuccess>
 </publishers>
</project> 
</cruisecontrol>
```

when i run cruisecontrol.bat in command everything go ok.
but i run cc as nt service give me error :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "projects/xxxx"): CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your SVN is located in a directory,which is included in the PATH environment variable for your Windows user account, but is not included in the PATH for the user account you are running the CC service as. Try either using full path to SVN.EXE or adding the SVN.EXE location to the machine-wide PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Subversion .exe path in CruiseControl's sourcecontrol block:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\svn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
etc...
</sourcecontrol>
```